# How to validate a List<Object> in a Primefaces dataTable - JSF

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have a dataTable for Phone something like :

```
<p:dataTable value="#{billingInfoBean.billingProfile.payer.phones}" var="phone" id="payerPhoneTable">

    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Type" />
        </f:facet>
        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{phone.type}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{backOfficeLookupClient.allPhoneTypes}" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Area Code" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:inputText value="#{phone.areaCode}" size="3" maxlength="3" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Exchange" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:inputText value="#{phone.exchange}" size="3" maxlength="3" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Local" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:inputText value="#{phone.local}" size="4" maxlength="4" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Extension" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:inputText value="#{phone.extension}" size="5" maxlength="5" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

I am trying to use custom validation using the object Phone. I need to call a Phone Validation service which takes these column values as inputs. Can I make use of `<f:validator>` here in this case?, If yes, how ?

Comment: That the halfbaked answer os StarsSky is been accepted implies that you have succeed and finished in implementing the concrete functional requirement. Is that true? This is in combination with an `UIData` component namely not as trivial as StarsSky is trying to imply. Besides that, the `<f:event>` is in essence an ugly hack for the particular requirement. There are cleaner ways,.

Comment: @BaluC: So, I didn't try it on the dataTable yet, but I've tried it on Address Validations, and however although I would used postValidate I still went with another method, and by the way it is one of the solution was provided in your blog itself.Happy to hear from the master itself:), I would love to take suggestions from you man! http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/12/validator-for-multiple-fields.html. Please let me know a cleaner solution.Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This omnifaces tag solved my problem :

http://showcase.omnifaces.org/validators/validateMultiple

Answer (score 2):

You could attach to the `dataTable` a validator listener

```
<f:event type="postValidate" listener="#{bean.customValidation}"/>
```

And validate the phone object in your bean

```
public void customValidation(ComponentSystemEvent event) {
    ...
}
```

Then iterate through all dataTable childrens and validate each one.

[Here](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/multi-components-validator-in-jsf-2-0/) ther's a good tutorial to start with.