# Is it possible to have a validator on a table?

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces

I have a list of tables created from a datamodel and on each of the tables I'd like to have a radiobutton with required selection(I use [RadioCheckBox](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.jsf)). On the submit, I'd like to highlight the tables where no selection has been made. It looks like this:

```
<p:dataList value="#{myBB.list}"
            var="list" itemType="none">
    <p:dataTable value="#{list.choices}" var="choice" rowKey="#{choice.id}"
                 selection="#{list.choice}">
        <p:column selectionMode="single"/>
        <!--other columns-->
    </p:dataTable>
</p:dataList>
```

I thought the way to go would be a custom validator, but the problem is I cannot attach validator to datatable or to the `<p:column selectionMode="single"/>` because I get "Parent not an instance of EditableValueHolder.

Is there some other way to do it? I can do the validation in the backing bean, but the problem is that the tables in the list are dynamic so I think it would be better to have a validator on every table. Is it even possible to have a table highlighted by validation? I'm not sure I've seen it somewhere else.

- Primefaces 4.0
- Mojarra 2.2.4

Comment: Attach a validator to the dataTable http://stackoverflow.com/a/21509639/2015318

Comment: Thanks. And I guess I can only make the radioButton highlighted(because setValid can be only called on EditableValueHolder). Not the whole table